# Why is the wrong version of Python launching?

Tags: shell, alias

Take a look. When I type python3 I want python3.6 to launch. Instead I am getting 3.5.2. There's something wrong with my path or alias or something else, but I can't spot it. I would love another set of eyes, thanks!

```
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Wrong version

```
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

According to the shell, I am getting /usr/local/bin/python3

```
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb 10 16:14 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Which is a symlink to python3.6

```
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ /usr/local/bin/python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Which indeed is the python I want

```
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ echo $PATH
```

And here's the path and the aliases:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$ alias
alias cm='cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make'
alias cs='cd ~/catkin_ws/src'
alias cu='cd ~/rosutils'
alias cw='cd ~/catkin_ws'
alias eb='nano ~/.bashrc'
alias gazempty='roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch'
alias gp='git pull'
alias gs='git status'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias restart='supervisorctl -u root -p dev@ros restart x:*'
alias sb='source ~/.bashrc'
alias settime='sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com'
alias teleop='roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch'
[PI]~/linorobot_ws/src/linorobot/teensy/firmware$
```

Comment: Does `hash -r` help by any chance?

Comment: Did you just now install Python 3.6, in that same shell session?  If so, see Stephen's comment.

Comment: What is the output of `command -v python3`? In general `which` is a poor (but very popular) way to check which command a shell will execute.